# Media elementd and HLS m3u

Tags: video, microsoft-metro, element, m3u

I got a question. Currently I am trying to develop media player for windows 8 metro app. In my project I am using media element which can play mp4 and supported format just fine. But I really need to use HLS m3u aswell for streaming and I cant even figure out if its possible or not. It its can somebody please explain me how ? I understand only that m3u is playlist and its not basically supported with media element. So please tell me is there a way how to play it with media element (or somehow bypass it ?) without creating a completly new player.

Atm I am using this

media.Source = new Uri("http://pseudo01.hddn.com/vod/demo.flowplayervod/bbb-800.**mp4**");

Its a test Url. The real URL will be provided by server and it will be something like this:

...vod/0b534658-1f73-483b-aebb-19a3dd5b91cd.mp4/playlist.**m3u8**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can open the m3u file and give the URL to the player. 
Also have a look at this
http://playerframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Windows%208%20Metro%20Player%3a%20Install%20and%20configure%20-%20XAML%2fC&referringTitle=Windows%208%20Metro%20Player%20Documentationhttp://